# EventListener does not get removed on function call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When routing to a different page the eventListener should be removed but it is not.
Might there be any reason this is happening?
The function is getting called.

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
        Resultaat(e.keyCode)
    })
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    window.document.removeEventListener("keydown", () => { })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add add/remove an event listener, you need to provide the same function
you can do this

```
componentDidMount() {
 window.document.addEventListener("keydown", this.handleKeyDown)
}
```

than remove it like

```
componentWillUnmount() {
 window.document.removeEventListener("keydown", this.handleKeyDown)
}
```

You can't pass anonymous function to window event listener

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

When removing the event listener you should pass on the same instance of the listener as you gave when setting it, i.e.:

```
var thisIsMyListener = (e) => {
        Resultaat(e.keyCode)
    };

componentDidMount() {
    window.document.addEventListener("keydown", thisIsMyListener)
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    window.document.removeEventListener("keydown", thisIsMyListener)
}
```

Since in JS a function is also an object, you should always provide the same instance of it.

Also, `() => {}` is stating an [anonymous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#The_function_expression_function_expression) function which always produces a new instance of this function.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to unbind a different method from the click event, than previously assigned. You can imagine as your anonymous function in the `addEventListener` method to point to a function called `fn1` and then you are trying to unassign a different function `fn2` from same eventListener. Therefore it doesn't remove the correct one.

Look at this example I provided for you:

https://jsfiddle.net/13oafx9b/

```
const button1 = document.getElementById('button');
const button2 = document.getElementById('button2');

function logSomething() {
    console.log('clicked');
}

button1.addEventListener('click', logSomething);

button2.addEventListener('click', () => {
    button1.removeEventListener('click', logSomething);
})
```

By creating a named function you end up with a memory pointer towards the reference of the function "logSomething" and use the exact same one to de-tach it again.

**edit**

In your comment you are creating another anonymous function `e => { Resultaat(e.keyCode); }` hence you end up without reference to it.
If you call it directly like `doc.addEventListener("keydown", Resultaat); });` you get the `e` passed down as first parameter to `Resultaat` where you can handle the logic for it. If you want to keep it like it was, with calling `Resultaat` with the `e.keyCode` event you have to wrap it in a named function ..

```
doc.addEventListener("keydown", printKeyCode); });

function printKeyCode(e) {
  Resultaat(e.keyCode);
}
```

Once again: `e => { Resultaat(e.keyCode); }` creates an anonymous unnamed function which cant be detached from the eventlistener since there is no reference to it from the removeEventListener function.

Comment: We need to get the keydowns from of the whole page. We tried your suggestion, but this only seems to work on specific elements and not  the whole page.

`
const doc = window.document;

 doc.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
      Resultaat(e.keyCode);
    });

`

Comment: That's because you are again creating an anonymous function.. :) ill update my answer for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the **SAME FUNCTION** to `removeEventListener` as you passed to `addEventListener`.

Declare the listener separately, you can then pass it to both. This is not the place to be using anonymous functions :)

```
var fn = (e) => Resultaat(e.keyCode)

window.document.addEventListener("keydown", fn)

window.document.removeEventListener("keydown", fn)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

and

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

are helpful...